# Prove that it is not a cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let´s $F_{x,y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if } x<0, y<0 \mbox{ or } x+y<1 \\
1& \mbox{in any other case }\end{cases}$

Prove that it is not a cumulative distribution function.

Hint $P(\frac{1}{2}<x <1 , \frac{1}{2}< y < 1) < 0$

I tryed this:

$P(\frac{1}{2}<x <1 , \frac{1}{2}< y < 1) = P(x <1 ,y< 1)-P(x\leq\frac{1}{2},  y < 1)-P(x <1 , y \leq\frac{1}{2})+P(x \leq \frac{1}{2} , y \leq\frac{1}{2}) = 1-1-1+1=0$

But, Where is my mistake? Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There's no mistake in your calculation.  The hint doesn't provide a disproof (assuming you've written $F_{x,y}$ correctly). In the hint, try $1/4$ in place of $1/2$.

Comment: Yes, I wrote $F_{x,y}$ correctly, if i use $1/4$ i have a different  result, thanks you for your help :)